# When I'm changing class name how change constructors names automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CostomException : Exception
    {
        public MyException() { }
        public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public MyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
        protected MyException(
          System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
          System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a "refactoring" tool (a question for such is out of scope on SO tough); consider ReSharper, CodeRush or VS builtin(?) capabilities.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you could select the class name, right click and select Refactor in the context menu, and select rename. (CTRL-R, CTRL-R)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you are using a tool like [Jetbrains' ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it will perform these refactors (and many others too!) for you.

It costs money to buy, but there is a free trial to see how you like it.

(Not affiliated with Jetbrains in any way, just a happy user of their products for years!)

Comment: This is an overkill for a simple class renaming. If you are not affiliated, you must be obsessed to propose the tool for such a simple thing. :P

Comment: Wow - I recommend a tool that was later recommended by other people also, and get an ad hominem attack for my trouble? Chill, dude.

Comment: Wasn't attacking, dude. Cool down. Added a :P to explicitly display the humorous tone I was assuming.

Comment: I like to recommend ReSharper whenever I can, simply because of how useful it is. Doesn't mean I am obsessed - just a keen user :)

Comment: "I like to recommend ReSharper whenever I can" obsessed! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rename refactor.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx)

As documented in official site :-

> Rename is a refactoring feature in the Visual Studio integrated
>   development environment (IDE) that provides an easy way to rename
>   identifiers for code symbols such as fields, local variables, methods,
>   namespaces, properties, and types. Rename can be used to change the
>   names in comments and in strings and to change the declarations and
>   calls of an identifier.

As given in Official document :-

> **Code Editor**
>
> In the Code Editor, rename refactoring is available when you position
>   the cursor on certain types of code symbols. When the cursor is in
>   this position, you can invoke the Rename command by typing the
>   keyboard shortcut (CTRL + R, CTRL + R), or by selecting the Rename
>   command from a smart tag, shortcut menu, or the Refactor menu.

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio, when we rename a class name(generally any identifier), the changes will not be reflected in all places where the class is been referred. But Visual Studio provides a ShortCut Key which can be used to rename any identifier in all places it is been referred. To achieve this once you renamed your class. Press `"CTRL + '.' "` key. A context menu will appear. Select Rename "OldName" to "NewName" option. All the referrences will be changed to new reference.

Comment: I'm renaming manually. I wont to press key for automatic rename constroctors.

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan Hi, can you elaborate how you rename manually??

Comment: clicked on classname and change name by typing. Need short key after that rename constroctors inside class.

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan : "clicked on classname and change name by typing" once after you changed clasname press "CTRL" key + "." (period Key). A context menu Will open, then click Rename. Are you clear now??

Answer (score 0):

VS has the builtin capacity to perform rename refactorings, default hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

I'd agree with Christian K's comment, there are really good refactoring tools out there that make you wonder how you ever worked without them.